# Current currency mode of an salesforce org

Tags: rest-api, multi-currency

Ran into a scenario where an org enabled advanced multi currency and populated records and decided to switch back to basic currency. They didn't delete records in the DatedCurrencyRate table after deciding to switch back.

Both CurrencyType and DatedConversionRate tables don't have any flag to indicate they are currently used/disabled.

Is there some other way to find this out using REST APIs?